# Infinite Pool process while work is achived, in python with function applied on a sequence of pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I splited a `pandas.DataFrame` into 6 parts with a similar shape's rows: `118317,118315,...` in order to balance the work and to respect the integrity of data to use `groupby` on a field.

These 6 parts are `pandas.DataFrame` stored in a `list`.

The function to apply, in parallel for each one, is the following.

```
def compute_recency (df):
    recency = df.groupby('name').apply(lambda x: x['date'] - x['date'].shift()).fillna(0).reset_index()
    df = df.join(recency.set_index('level_1'), rsuffix= '_f')
    return df
```

Then I parallelized the processes as :

```
import multiprocessing as mp

cores=mp.cpu_count()

pool = mp.Pool(cores)

df_out = pool.map(compute_recency, list_of_6_dataframes)

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

The issue is it keeps calculating in the jupyter lab's notebook => `[*]`, while I can see in my resources monitor that the CPUs are now "free", I mean they are not at 100% as at first.

Note if I use the following function:

```
def func(df):
    return df.shape
```

It works well and quickly, no `[*]` for the eternity.

So I guess the issue is from the function `compute_recency` but I don't see why. 
Can you help me ?

---

Pandas version: 0.23.4 
 Python version: 3.7.4

Comment: have you tested the use of your function without using `mp`? To see if it works as expected?

Comment: @Robert of course, on a single dataframe it works fine.

Comment: What is the purpose of this function? could you add some sample data using: `df = pd.DataFrame({...})`? What is the reason you want to use `mp` to perform this task?

Comment: The purpose of the function is to compute the difference btw two dates represented in each row, all of that with `groupby` because it is dependent of each `name`. The reason why I want to use `mp` is the dataframe itself is big, and it can take minutes to apply.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little difficult to see what might be causing an issue here. Perhaps since you are using `multiprocessing` maybe break your data up into the groups created by `groupby`? and then process each group using multiprocessing?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
groups = [x for _, x in df.groupby("name")]

def add_new_col(x):
    x['new'] = x['date'] - x['date'].shift().fillna(0)
    return x

p = Pool()
groups = p.map(add_new_col, groups)
df = pd.concat(groups, ignore_index=True)
p.close()
p.join()
```

by the way, in regards to your original code. `p.map` will return a list of dataframes not a dataframe. Which is why I've used `pd.concat` to combine the results at the end.

Comment: I know `df_out = pool.map(compute_recency, list_of_6_dataframes)` does not return a dataframe, sorry if it was confusing. I let it in a list because this is not the only transformation I will make.
It seems what cause issue is to put the two operations in one function. So I did, one function to compute as your `add_new_col(x)` and one function to join and map it with a list containing tuple as `(df,serie_to_join)`, it is greatly better.